# How to convert multiple images to one pdf file

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf

I'm developing an app which take multiple images from a folder and convert them into single pdf file please help?

Comment: Show your code for one.

Comment: What specific do you need help with?

Comment: No i need just line of code which convert multiple images to pdf please help